# Dockerfile RUN behaviors differently for different folders

Tags: docker, ansible, permissions, dockerfile

Note: the issue is reproduced, only when docker is handled via Ansible modules.

Docker image is built via Ansible, and then a Container is created and started.

I am running Ansible task as `alex` user with `become` option enabled.

`Dockerfile` is handled via Ansible template, here is an adjusted `Dockerfile` file (for simplification), stored in `/home/alex/mysql` folder:

```
ARG mysql_version

FROM mysql/mysql-server:$mysql_version

RUN mkdir -p /home/mysql/logs  && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql/logs && \
    mkdir -p /home/mysql/lib && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql/lib
```

Ansible default variables for the mysql role:

```
---
mysql_conf_host_path: /home/{{ lookup('env', 'USER') }}/mysql
mysql_log_path_host: /var/log/mysql
mysql_log_path_container: /home/mysql/logs
mysql_data_path_host: /var/lib/mysql
mysql_data_path_container: /home/mysql/lib
mysql_version: 8.0.21
docker_mysql_image_name: bm_my_sql
docker_mysql_container_name: bm_my_sql
```

Ansible tasks (implemented as a `mysql` role) to build image, create container and start it:

```
- name: "Build {{ docker_mysql_image_name }}:{{ mysql_version }} Docker image"
  docker_image:
    source: build
    build:
      path: "{{ mysql_conf_host_path }}" 
      args:
        mysql_version: "{{ mysql_version }}"
    name: "{{ docker_mysql_image_name }}:{{ mysql_version }}" # contain lowercase letters, numbers or - and _.
    state: present

- name: "Create {{ docker_mysql_container_name }} container"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ docker_mysql_container_name }}"
    image: "{{ docker_mysql_image_name }}:{{ mysql_version }}"
    env:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "{{ mysql_root_pwd }}"
    volumes:
      - "{{ mysql_log_path_host }}:{{ mysql_log_path_container }}"
      - "{{ mysql_data_path_host }}:{{ mysql_data_path_container }}"
    state: present

- name: "Start {{ docker_mysql_container_name }} container"
  docker_container:
    name: "{{ docker_mysql_container_name }}"
    state: started
```

Then log to the container and see if chown is applied:

```
$ docker exec -it bm_my_sql bash
bash-4.2# ls -la /home/mysql/lib/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 16:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 24 16:39 ..
bash-4.2# ls -la /home/mysql/logs/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 24 16:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 24 16:39 ..
```

Folders are created, but the owner is still root.

Before I played with changing owner on other folders. And it showed strange result. For instance in the Dockerfile 2 directory trees were created and chown was invoked for each one:

```
ARG mysql_version

FROM mysql/mysql-server:$mysql_version

RUN mkdir -p /home/a/b/c && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /home/a/b/c

RUN mkdir -p /var/log/mysql/a/b/c && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql/a/b/c
```

The result on the container, only folder and owner of `/home/a/b/c` is changed.

`/var/log/mysql/a/b/c` does not exist. `/var/log/mysql/` exists in original "parent" image.

What might be the reason of this and how to force creating of `/var/log/mysql/a/b/c` directory tree with an owner?

The behavious with these folders was not consistent. Sometimes it did not work, sometimes worked.

Created an [issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/71427) for Ansible community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to reproduce and everything looks fine on my end. After building the image from the Dockerfile example that you provided, things look like this, inside the container:

```
sh-4.2# ls -la /var/log/mysql/a/b/c
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 24 14:37 . <-- the current directory (/var/log/mysql/a/b/c) has the mysql owner and group(if there would have been children entities in this directory, their owner would have also been changed because of the -R option you used.
drwxr-xr-x 3 root  root  4096 Aug 24 14:37 .. <-- the parent directory (/var/log/mysql/a/b) is owned by root, hence the mkdir -p was executed as root
```

Perhaps you are also declaring a VOLUME in that Dockerfile in the same path? If any build steps change the data within the volume after it has been declared, those changes will be discarded.

---

**Edit after update 2 in question:**

Step by step on my side:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM mysql/mysql-server:8.0.21

RUN mkdir -p /home/mysql/logs  && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql/logs && \
    mkdir -p /home/mysql/lib && \
    chown -R mysql:mysql /home/mysql/lib
```

Build command:

```
docker image build -t so-weird-chown .
```

Open console in container and check ownership:

```
docker run -it so-weird-chown sh
[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.21-1.1.17


sh-4.2# ls -la /home/mysql/logs
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 24 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Aug 24 16:35 ..
sh-4.2# ls -la /home/mysql/lib
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Aug 24 16:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root  4096 Aug 24 16:35 ..
```

Comment: which mysql_version did you use? I used 8.0.21. I do not use any volumes in my Dockerfile. I run it via Ansile docker_image module. Probably it might affect somehow.

Comment: I've just tried to build it without version, and it also worked. It seems there is a bug with 8.0.21

Comment: latest(mysql/mysql-server:8.0.21-1.1.17). I am rebuilding now with  8.0.21

Comment: Cannot get it, but it works now and with 8.0.21. (Not sure about 1.1.17, where to see it). Absolutely strange. But thank you for your investigation and time

Comment: Yes, you're right: something strange is happening in 8.0.21. I am experiencing the same problem with 8.0.21. `sh-4.2# cd var/log/mysql/a/b/c  
sh: cd: var/log/mysql/a/b/c: No such file or directory`

Comment: where can I see, is it 8.0.21 or 8.0.21-1.1.17

Comment: Something strange is going on. It seems that `latest`, `8.0.21-1.1.17` and `8.0.21` are the same. Well...if you passed the `8.0.21` argument at build time, then the `8.0.21` must have been used. But the strange thing is that I just build from `8.0.21` and when I ran the container, the first log is `[Entrypoint] MySQL Docker Image 8.0.21-1.1.17`. I have to dig a little bit further

Comment: I have not idea what happened, but I can no longer reproduce regardless of the version I am using. I have rebuilt with `8.0.21`, `8.0.21-1.1.17` and `latest` - they all have the same digest. My `/var/log/mysql/a/b/c` is always correctly created now. Not sure if the issue opened on github will receive any resolution hence I've no idea how to reproduce that one more time :)

Comment: I've changed paths, not folders are updated, not owner is still root. And nothing happens at all. How it is possible to work this way?

Comment: Can you please share the exact `Dockerfile`, `docker build` and `docker run` commands, or simply replace the `$mysql_version` with the hardcoded value you're using? Once again it simply works on my end. I am updating my answer with the exact Dockerfile that I am using.

Comment: I've updated my post, by including Ansible-related data.